# Xamarin iOS: Downcasting segue.DestinationViewController Error

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, segue

I set up a segue with a navigation controller in Xamarin.iOS. The first screen is just a ViewController that has a List of phoneNumbers, and adds to the list of phone numbers when a button is clicked. When a different button is clicked, I want to go to the CallHistory2 screen and display the list of phone numbers. However, I'm having trouble passing the List object to the second screen.

This is a method in the ViewController.cs class (the first screen)

```
public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
   base.PrepareForSegue (segue, sender);

   // set the View Controller that’s powering the screen we’re
   // transitioning to

   var callHistoryContoller = segue.DestinationViewController as CallHistory2;

   //set the Table View Controller’s list of phone numbers to the
   // list of dialed phone numbers

   if (callHistoryContoller != null) {
      callHistoryContoller.PhoneNumbers = PhoneNumbers;
   }
 }
```

I get an error at this line

```
var callHistoryContoller = segue.DestinationViewController as CallHistory2;
```

Cannot convert type 'UIKit.UIViewController' to 'PortableAppTest.iOS.CallHistory2' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion PortableAppTest.iOS

When I change `CallHistory2` to `UITableViewController` the error goes away, but then `callHistoryController` won't contain a reference to my `CallHistory2`  class (implements `UITableViewController`), but rather to a generic `UITableViewController` class.

How do I work around this issue? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try following, It will work .

```
if ( segue.DestinationViewController.GetType() == typeof(CallHistory2))
 {
CallHistory2 callHistoryContoller = (CallHistory2)segue.DestinationViewController
callHistoryContoller.PhoneNumbers = PhoneNumbers;

}
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to do that: Cannot convert type 'UIKit.UIViewController' to 'PortableAppTest.iOS.CallHistory2'. It says a potential fix is removing the redundant cast `(CallHistory2)` but when I remove that I get this error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'UIKit.UIViewController' to 'PortableAppTest.iOS.CallHistory2'"

Comment: Whats type of your CallHistyory2? I mean whats base class?

Comment: UITableViewController

Comment: strange, Should work if its UItableviewcontroller. I have same code working. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2b7ee8fa38302d958e502c2416360b9920161220070724/4d93f0  may be problem with version of Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone else as I ran into the same issue!

This is from Xamarins Multiscreen guide

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_iOS_multiscreen/hello,_iOS_multiscreen_quickstart/

And the issue for me was that the app is called "PhoneWord" but the code for this Viewcontroller was using "Phoneword" as the namespace (notice the lower case W)

As soon as I set it correctly it worked as expected.